# Computer randomly restarts - no indicators/crash logs/BSOD

Tags: windows-10, reboot, random

So my desktop machine has started randomly restarting with no prompt, no BSOD, no error messages or the like.

There is no consistency to it, it can happen when the machine is idle, or under load when gaming. Some days it doesn't even happen at all! This is the same machine I have had for over 3 years and this is a very new problem and I cannot associate it with any newly downloaded programs.

The only thing I can think of that's changed is I recently downloaded and installed Windows updates a few weeks ago, roughly when this first started (i think?). However I have downloaded multiple updates since and I have no way of knowing which update it was.

I ran a memory test and no issues were flagged as a result of that. The machine is water-cooled and so there's not a speck of dust inside the machine. I have also turned off the "automatically restart" option under system failure in system settings so it's not this either.

My computer is also not generating any .dmp files by virture of the crashes (at least none that I can locate or find by searching ".dmp" even though I have it set to automatic memory dump.

This is my first post so apologies if I am missing any details. I copy some below that you may find helpful.

```
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎28/‎04/‎2021
OS build    19042.985
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz   4.20 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May be your OS is not crashing but PC is Resetting as if Reset Button is pressed. At a very basic level Reset Button could be faulty. Remove the Reset Pin from the motherboard header for a while and observe. If the issue repeats it’s most likely a hardware fault. If so, motherboard or PSU are the likely candidates.

Comment: Theoretically, power interruption may be the culprit here. Beyond the Reset Button/Power Switch, PSU and motherboard, it might be worth considering any power interruptions, power adapter, power cord or maybe even loose internal wiring.

Comment: Have you tried a new PSU, power cable or socket? And just to be clear, there is nothing in the event viewer log?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple crashes, no dump files.

You said you tested memory.

Check Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Maintenance, and list Reliability History. Look for errors there that may be enlightening. If automatic memory dumps are truly on, then a restart crash because of Windows should leave a dump file.

**To enable mini dumps:**

In Control Panel, System and Security, System. Select Advanced system settings, Advanced tab.

In the Startup and Recovery area, select Settings and ensure (re-verify) dump files are enabled.

Then, given the above, I suggest Power Supply issue or Motherboard issue.

Probably time to get the machine serviced at a local shop.

Comment: "even though I have it set to automatic memory dump." ???